# Allow user to choose from his own referenced nodes

Tags: drupal-7, entityreference, drupal-contextual-filters

I have two content types:

1. Business listing
2. Product listing.

"Product listing" has an Entity Reference field. This field points to the nodes of "business listing". I want to allow user to choose from his own "business listing" nodes (during adding a "product listing" node). I have created a view to list the nodes of "business listing" type and have added an Entity Reference display to the view. Then I selected the view Under "Entity selection". Now, I have a problem in adding proper contextual filter. I have added a contextual filter of "Content: Author Uid" and selected "provide default value".

a) if I select "USER ID from logged in user" as default value:

This solution will break if an admin is editing the node. The field will then show only nodes the current user (admin) has created.

b) if I select {"User ID from URL" and "Also look for a node and use the node author"}: This solution will break if an user is adding a new node. The field will not show any nodes! http://example.com/node/add

please guide me